# Does bash (or zsh) "officially" mandate the use of tabs for indentation in scripts?

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, zsh, indentation

I recently came across the following statement ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33817423/559827); emphasis added):

> For shell scripts, using tabs is not a matter of preference or style; *it's how the language is defined*.

I am trying to make sense of this claim.  Of course, it is somewhat loosely worded<sup>1</sup>, but I would like to know if there is any truth to it.

In particular, I would like to know if the official documentation for either bash or zsh (the two shells I routinely write scripts for) say anything approaching a mandate or recommendation to use tabs for indentation of source code.  (I would appreciate explicit references to the supporting paragraphs in this documentation.)

(FWIW, let me point out that I am aware of the fact that, in practice, both bash and zsh readily interpret scripts that are *not* indented exclusively with tabs.  Therefore, I don't expect the documentation for either shell to go much further than a strong recommendation, if they mention the matter at all.)

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> For one thing, it refers simultaneously to "shell scripts" and "the language", which contradicts the facts that there are multiple shells in current use, each defining its own language.</sup>

Comment: I edited the SO answer to clarify that it is only referring to heredocs and not to shell scripts in general.

Comment: it says "the shell language" without specification, but that question is tagged for Bash, so it's a safe assumption that they mean the language Bash accepts. Or the POSIX shell language, which is the relevant part here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand it, the claim is being made specifically in the context of here-documents, and [the `<<-` form specifically strips leading tabs](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_04):

> If the redirection operator is "`<<-`", all leading <tab> characters shall be stripped from input lines and the line containing the trailing delimiter.

Note that the second script in that answer *doesn’t* use tabs, which would be surprising if the author considered that indentation was required to use tabs.